# Remove records from 1 query based on same values found in another query

Tags: c#, linq

So I have 2 `IQueryable<Array>` queries with a common string type; I want to use the second query to remove all records using the common type in the first, leaving only the records not found as the result of the first query. Not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Show us the code you have? What you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to do it:

IQueryable<LISTA> a = db.ListA.Where(x => x.Active);
IQueryable<LISTB> b = db.ListB.Where(x => x.HadReview);

a = a.Concat(x => x.LogginID == b.Any.LogginID);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most understandable way to do it is to filter out the items in ListA using `Where()`:

```
IQueryable<LISTA> as = db.ListA.Where(x => x.Active);
IQueryable<LISTB> bs = db.ListB.Where(x => x.HadReview);
as = as.Where(a => bs.Any(b => a.LogginID == b.LogginID) == false);
```

A way that might be more efficient is to use a [Group Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx):

```
var as = from a in db.ListA.Where(x => x.Active)
         join b in db.ListB.Where(x => x.HadReview) 
             on a.LogginID equals b.LogginID into bs
         where bs.Any() == false
         select a;
```

**Edit:** If you have two different DataContexts the above will not work.  This might:

```
IQueryable<LISTA> as = db1.ListA.Where(x => x.Active);
IQueryable<LISTB> bs = db2.ListB.Where(x => x.HadReview);
as = as.Where(a => bs.Select(b => b.LogginID).Contains(a.LogginID) == false);
```

See also: [Linq to SQL - How to inner join tables from different Data Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537805/linq-to-sql-how-to-inner-join-tables-from-different-data-context)

Comment: Great solution thank you, however I have a further issue.  Each of the queries are on a different datacontext.  Can you assist me which way I can get that to work?

Comment: To get around my issue above I have done the following, the Any() method could not be used as it caused another issue.

var as = prdb.LISTA.Where(x => x.Active).Select(x => x.StaffUsername).ToArray();
var bs = syndb.LISTB.Where(x => x.ActiveFlag);
bs = bs.Where(x => !r.Contains(x.Community.NetworkLogin));

This solution fixed the 'different datacontext' issue and the issue with .Any() which I changed to .Contains() that followed.

Comment: @JeffreyJ: There might be a way to perform the query without storing anything in local memory.  See my edit.